# Cant read the value of a object

Tags: javascript, exception

i am writing a function where i want to do something and if it went wrong catch the status code of it. bellow is my function

```
 client.leads.listBy({
     email: lead.email
 }).then((res) => {

    //do somthing
 }).catch((err) => {

     if (typeof err.statusCode != 'undefined') {
         console.log("the");
     } else {
         console.log(err);
     }


 });
```

this is the exception i am getting

```
Error: {"statusCode":404,"body":{"type":"error.list","request_id":"b1fgpg7ovmtufdj5trn0","errors":[{"code":"not_found","message":"User Not Found"}]},"headers":{"cache-control":"no-cache","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","date":"Fri, 09 Feb 2018 20:12:53 GMT","server":"nginx","set-cookie":["_mkra_ctxt=2c440af4e2742721616aff3205dba2a6--404; path=/; max-age=5; HttpOnly; secure"],"status":"404 Not Found","strict-transport-security":"max-age=31557600; includeSubDomains; preload","vary":"Accept-Encoding","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-intercom-version":"e371d2ed50f488065fd36fb728b849d66e3846c2","x-ratelimit-limit":"83","x-ratelimit-remaining":"36","x-ratelimit-reset":"1518207180","x-request-id":"b1fgpg7ovmtufdj5trn0","x-runtime":"0.049997","x-xss-protection":"1; mode=block","transfer-encoding":"chunked","connection":"Close"},"request":{"uri":{"protocol":"https:","slashes":true,"auth":null,"host":"api.intercom.io","port":null,"hostname":"api.intercom.io","hash":null,"search":"?email=nicole.goncalves%40mvfglobal.com","query":"email=nicole.goncalves%40mvfglobal.com","pathname":"/users","path":"/users?email=nicole.goncalves%40mvfglobal.com","href":"https://api.intercom.io/users?email=nicole.goncalves%40mvfglobal.com"},"method":"get","headers":{"Accept":"application/json","User-Agent":"intercom-node-client/2.0.0","authorization":"Basic ZEc5ck9tSTVOakUzTW1JNFgyWmlNRGhmTkdZeVlWODVZVEF6WDJOa01qazROakl3T0RRME16b3hPakE9Og==","content-length":0}}}
```

i am tring to access this by `err.statusCode` but it does not work. how  do i get the statuscode. it always go to else condition and print the err

Comment: Are you sure that this is the exact place where the code logs the err object? Because this works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/n6yddzg2/

Comment: @ChrisG am 100% sure. this is the only function that gets a 404 status code. and i have added another log below that. as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got this error because you trying to access a `statusCode` of a string. I guess `client.leads.listBy` does stringify the error and calls `throw new Error(stringifiedObj)`, so you can't access its properties at `catch` block in the end. Otherwise you would got [Object object] as output.

Alright, I got it for you. What you see in the console output is an error message which is a string. Here's what you want to do inside `catch` block to check the actual property:

```
const errObj = JSON.parse(err.message)
if (errObj.statusCode !== undefined) {
     console.log("the");
} else {
     console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: no the type is object `Worker.Node.2b0c2c75-a484-4497-acdb-d1310408c93e[0]
      object
`

Comment: Exception itself indeed is an object. What you got in you console is its message which is a string. I'll edit my answer to make it more clear

Comment: how to stript the Error: part cant replace getting a error saying  `err.replace is not a function`

what i did 

 `var ret = err.replace('Error:','');
                        var arr = JSON.parse(ret);
                       
                        console.log(arr.statusCode);`

Comment: Just figured out what you should do (see my answer). Sorry for this misleading. I got everything wrong for some reason.

Comment: it gives me this error `Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0` cant parse it that way

Comment: fixed again. try it.